# Fluent NHibnernate HasManyToMany with Index

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to map a many-to-many collection with Fluent NHibnernate.  My model class has this property:

```
public virtual IList<Resource> Screenshots
{
    get { return _screenshots; }
    protected set { _screenshots = value; }
}
```

And my fluent mapping is:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Screenshots)
                .AsList(x => x.WithColumn("Index"))
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

When I run my application, I get the following exception message:

> The element 'list' in namespace
>   'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has
>   invalid child element 'many-to-many'
>   in namespace
>   'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'. List of
>   possible elements expected: 'index,
>   list-index' in namespace
>   'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.

There should be a way to do this.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a link table for your many to many relation?

Comment: I have since discovered that this was a bug in Fluent NHibnernate.  It is documented as fixed in the latest build.

Comment: You may want to answer this yourself with the link to that bug report and any applicable version numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The current FluentNHibernate syntax for this is as follows:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Screenshots)
    .AsList(i => i.Column("`Index`"));
```

The index column defaults to Index, but that's a reserved word on SQL Server (and probably other databases too), so you must quote it with back-ticks.

Also, I'd recommend against setting a cascade on this relationship.  Consider the following code:

```
x.Screenshots.Remove(s);
session.SaveOrUpdate(x);
```

NHibernate will correctly delete rows from the linking table even without a cascade specified.  However, if you specify AllDeleteOrphan, then NHibernate will delete the row from the linking table and also delete Resource `s`.  I doubt this is the behavior you want on a many-to-many relationship.